# Covariant derivative of second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from 1706th page of Zhao Liang's *[The first eigenvalue of Laplace operator under powers of mean curvature flow](http://xueshu.baidu.com/s?wd=paperuri%3A%28dd325744683216d9b17ff64cde850cf3%29&filter=sc_long_sign&tn=SE_xueshusource_2kduw22v&sc_vurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fmathscinet-getitem%3Fmr%3D3057347&ie=utf-8&sc_us=6811413051064070287)*.

$g_{ij}$ is Riemannian metric, $h_{ij}$ is second fundamental form, and $H=g^{ij}h_{ij}$. $\nabla$ is Riemannian connect, and $\nabla^pH=g^{pl}\nabla_lH$. $h$ is a constant independ to $x$.

For getting the below equation, I get stuck at
$$
g^{ij}g^{pl}H^k\nabla_lh_{ij}-2g^{ij}g^{pl}H^k\nabla_ih_{jl}=-H^k\nabla^pH
$$
How should I to do it ?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

$$g^{ij} \nabla_l h_{ij} = \nabla_l (g^{ij} h_{ij}) = \nabla _l H$$

as $\nabla_l g^{ij} = 0$. Thus

$$g^{ij}g^{pl}H^k\nabla_lh_{ij}=g^{pl} H^k\nabla_l H = H^k\nabla^pH$$

by definition of $\nabla ^p = g^{pl}\nabla_l$.

For the next term, it is important to remark that one is working on hypersurfaces in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. In particular the ambient curvature is zero and the Codazzi equation gives

$$\nabla_i h_{lj} - \nabla_l h_{ij} =0.$$

Thus we have 
$$-2g^{ij}g^{pl}H^k\nabla_ih_{jl}=-2g^{ij}g^{pl}H^k\nabla_lh_{ij}=-2g^{pl}H^k\nabla_lH = -2H^k\nabla^pH.$$